# jQuery Lightbox similar with Facebook's new Photo Viewer

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Is there any jQuery lightbox plugin similar with Facebook's new Photo Viewer?
Specifically, I'm looking for a plugin where it can:

- be called programmatically
- show scrollbar according to new content
  displayed (if it's longer than screen height)
- show as modal dialog

EDIT: I have a list with items that when clicked, the lightbox will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a huge fan of Fancybox:

http://fancybox.net/

You probably would an iframe in the fancybox